# bug in python target of antlr

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

The python code generated by antlr-4.9 has some syntax problems. Eg, for the following antlr grammar:

```
e returns [ObjExpr v]
    : a=e op=('*'|'/') b=e  {
$v = ObjExpr($op.type)
$v.e1 = $a.v
$v.e2 = $b.v
}
    | INT                   {
$v = ObjExpr(21)
$v.i = $INT.int
}
    ; 

MUL : '*' ;
DIV : '/' ;
INT :   [0-9]+ ;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

The code generated is:

```
    localctx.v = ObjExpr((0 if localctx.op is None else localctx.op.type())
    localctx.v.e1 = localctx.a.v
    localctx.v.e2 = localctx.b.v
```

Whereas, the correct code should be:

```
localctx.v = ObjExpr((0 if localctx.op is None else localctx.op.type))
localctx.v.e1 = localctx.a.v
localctx.v.e2 = localctx.b.v
```

i.e., the code indentation is wrong, and the number of braces dont match. Manually editing the generated parser file to fix these errors makes the code run properly. How do I report this bug and get it fixed?

Comment: Open an issue for this problem in the ANTLR4 [issue tracker](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues).

Comment: Thanks, submitted issue #3011